# Wireless not working/ Wireless enabling dysfunction

Tags: wireless, icons

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.1, though I am continuously running into the same networking error. Whenever I boot Ubuntu, it takes me to the desktop perfectly, but when the wireless connection says its connected, it does not allow me to surf firefox due to a lack of connection though the icon on the top right says it is connected. Also, when rebooting, the wireless icon will at times have trouble enabling to turn on, even when it says its already enabled, hence continuing the problem in more depth with the connection error. How can I fix my wireless connection to work properly?

Comment: So I hit Ctrl + Alt + T for command prompt. I entered sudo apt-get install wicd, and right off the bat it gave me an E: Unable to locate package wicd. What should I do?

Comment: Also when entering `etc/network/interfaces` it tells me `Permission Denied`. I managed to install `Wicd` Network Manager and I removed the Connection Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid off from the Network manager on Ubuntu. Before doing it, first, install `Wicd` Network manager by `sudo apt-get install wicd`, then remove the connection manager `sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager`. check if you have any settings on `/etc/network/interfaces` just keep

```
   auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

then `Wicd` should give you what you want

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/256916). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: So I hit Ctrl + Alt + T for command prompt. I entered sudo apt-get install wicd, and right off the bat it gave me an E: Unable to locate package wicd. What should I do?