# How do I enable Wireless networking with an Atheros 9485 device?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, atheros

I have an Asus vivobook with Windows 8 preinstalled and tried dual boot with ubuntu. I'm new to linux and this was my first install. I installed ubuntu 12.10 but I couldn't connect to wireless network. did some googling and tried some suggestions but now I don't even have the choice to enable wireless networking. I can only connect to the internet by wired connection.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid off from the Network manager on Ubuntu. Before doing it, first, install `Wicd` Network manager by `sudo apt-get install wicd`, then remove the connection manager `sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager`. check if you have any settings on `/etc/network/interfaces` just keep

```
   auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

then `Wicd` should give you what you want

Comment: hi Sven, thanks for helping me
wicd installed but unable to locate gnome network manager.

Comment: does Wicd solve your problem?

Comment: still no wireless network found.

Comment: what does iwconfig outputs? if you don't have that tool, you can install it by "apt-get install wireless-tools"

Comment: @sven Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/256908). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: iwconfig says no wireless extensions

Comment: how about lspci output? you can post the output on pastebin.com

Comment: network controller: atheros ar9485 wireless network adapter rev 01

Comment: type "lsmod | grep ath9k", does it output anything?

Comment: I got no output at all

Comment: then you don't have the atherous driver for your wifi card. type "sudo modprobe ath9k" which will load the driver module. then check "lsmod | grep ath9k" to see the output, then type "iwconfig" if you see any wireless extension available

Comment: kapoek@kapoek-S400CA:~$ lsmod | grep ath9k
ath9k                 131308  0 
mac80211              539908  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           14055  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              395218  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    23827  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              206566  4 ath9k,mac80211,ath,rndis_wlan

Comment: kapoek@kapoek-S400CA:~$ iwconfig
usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

Comment: it seems like your wifi adapter is working, now you Wicd, you should be connected to your Access point

Comment: let me know if you are able to connect to your AP or not

Comment: FYI, you cannot use both Wifi and ethernet interface on Wicd at the same time.

Comment: i tried to connect to my phone hotspot but wicd told me no wireless network found. but now the option to enable wireless is back again. turn it on and off but nothing changed

Comment: Thanks Sven now I'm connected to the hotspot now going to try a reboot

Comment: I would first try to connect to my access point to see if you are able to use the wifi interface without any problem. if iwconfig outputs that your wlan0 interface works, then it should not be any problem to connect to an access point. check if iwlist wlan0 scan is able to scan available wireless networks. if you are able to see the available wireless networks, then you might have problem on your phone's setting to share the internet.

Comment: I could connect to the hotspot and connect to the internet. wlan0 interface worked and iwlist could scan available network. But after reboot i had to repeat all the step starting from sudo modprobe ath9k.

Comment: wicd still says no wireless network found, i can only connect to my phone hotspot from default network manager

Comment: Guys, can I suggest moving this to chat? Using comments in this way (such an extended conversation) is discouraged.